# Rails route rewriting with params lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

is there a way to rewrite a route before it's matched (sort of a before_filter) so that I can read and parse the request?

For example, if I receive this PUT request

```
http://localhost:3000/post
```

and a `params[:my_id]` exists (with value `my_value`), rewrite it as

```
http://localhost:3000/post/my_value
```

and hence have it matched by the appropriate route for a PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a piece of Rack middleware: specifically, [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite).

If rack-rewrite won't solve this problem for you, you might have to write your own middleware. The [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html) is a good place to start, but you'll otherwise probably have to Google around a little bit to figure out the correct syntax you're looking for and how to exactly achieve what you want.